How to complete this argument for going from a finitely additive to a countably additive set function on a semialgebra?
I'm stuck on the following exercise in Rosenthal's A First Look at Rigorous Probability Theory, paraphrased:

Let $\mathcal J$ be a semialgebra of subsets of $\Omega$. Suppose $P: \mathcal J \to [0,1]$ has the following two properties:

$P$ is finitely additive on $\mathcal J$. That is, if $D_1, \dots, D_n$ are disjoint sets in $\mathcal J$ and $\bigcup_{j=1}^n D_j
\in \mathcal J$, then $$P \left( \bigcup_{j=1}^n D_j \right) =
\sum_{j=1}^n P(D_j).$$
If $A_1, A_2, \dotsc \in \mathcal J$ such that $A_1 \supseteq A_2 \supseteq \dots$ and
$\bigcap_{j=1}^\infty A_j = \emptyset$, then $\lim_{n \to \infty}
P(A_n) = 0$.

Prove that $P$ is in fact countably additive on $\mathcal J$. [Hint: Set $A_n = (\bigcup_{j=1}^\infty D_j) \setminus (\bigcup_{i=1}^n D_i)$.]

A semialgebra $\mathcal J$ is defined to be a collection of subsets of $\Omega$ which contains $\emptyset$ and $\Omega$, is closed under finite intersections, and has the property that the complement of any element of $\mathcal J$ is a finite disjoint union of elements of $\mathcal J$.
Apparently there are errors in this exercise. Indeed this has been pointed out in an answer to a related question. Consulting the published errata for the book, we find that the sets $A_1, A_2, \dots$ should be finite disjoint unions of elements of $\mathcal J$, and that $P$ is extended to such sets by finite additivity.
Even with those corrections I am still stuck, however. I would very much appreciate some pointers, since the conclusion of this exercise is used later in the book.
My attempt
Let $\{D_1, D_2, \dotsc\}$ be a countably infinite collection of disjoint sets in $\mathcal J$, with $\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty D_i \in \mathcal J$. We wish to prove that $P (\bigcup_{j=1}^\infty D_j) = \sum_{j=1}^\infty P(D_j)$.
Following the hint, we define
$$A_n = \left( \bigcup_{j=1}^\infty D_j \right) \setminus \left( \bigcup_{i=1}^n D_i \right) = \bigcup_{j=n+1}^\infty D_j$$
for all $n \ge 1$. Suppose we could prove that each set $A_n$ is a finite disjoint union of elements of $\mathcal J$. Then we would have
$$P \left( \bigcup_{i=1}^\infty D_i \right) = P \left[ \left( \bigcup_{i=1}^n D_i \right) \cup A_n \right] = P \left( \bigcup_{i=1}^n D_i \right) + P(A_n)  = \sum_{i=1}^n P(D_i) + P(A_n)$$
for all $n$. We would also have $\lim_{n \to \infty} P(A_n) = 0$, since the sets $A_n$ make up a decreasing sequence with intersection $\bigcap_{j=1}^\infty A_j = \emptyset$. Thus the desired result would follow.
This certainly seems to be the intended solution method, but are the sets $A_n$ really finite disjoint unions of elements of $\mathcal J$? If yes, how would one go about proving it? If no, is there some other way to prove the result? If no again, can the construction be salvaged with some reasonable additional assumption (that, perhaps, the author forgot about)?

It is very confusing, IMO, that probabilists do not like working with infinite measures. They insist in not using infinite measure and then suddenly they have to deal with Lebesgue measures. Anyway... continuity from above is much more delicate than continuity from below. That is convergence of an increasing sequence is much easier to handle. $P(D) = \lim_n P(\bigcup_{j=1}^n D_j) = \lim_n \sum_{j=1}^n P(D_j) = \sum_{j=1}^\infty P(D_j)$.

@AndréCaldas I might be misunderstanding you, but it seems like you are assuming that $P$ is a measure here. But it is merely a function with the stated properties. (Though of course the end goal is to construct a probability measure.)

Yes, you are misunderstanding me. My point is that if assumption (2) (decreasing sequence) is changed to "increasing sequence", the demonstration is quite easy. Property (2) is not even valid for non finite measures, but it the "increasing version" is always valid. $\bigcup_{j=1}^n D_j \uparrow D$. Of course, the "weaker" increasing version is a consequence of the decreasing version, you just have to take the difference (as the hint instructs you).

Upon returning to this, I seem to have found a way to show that the sets $A_n$ are indeed finite disjoint unions of elements in $\cal J$.
Note first of all that if $A, B \in \mathcal J$, then $A \setminus B$ is a disjoint union of elements of $\mathcal J$. (Indeed some sources make this part of the definition.) To see this, note that $B^c$ is such a union, by the definition of a semialgebra. That is, $B^c = J_1 \cup \dots \cup J_k$ for some collection of disjoint sets $J_1, \dots, J_k \in \mathcal J$. Hence
$$A \setminus B = A \cap B^c = A \cap (J_1 \cup \dots \cup J_k) = (A \cap J_1) \cup \dots \cup (A \cap J_k).$$
The sets $A \cap J_i$ are elements of $\mathcal J$ by closure under finite intersections, and they are disjoint since the sets $J_i$ are disjoint. The result follows.
With that settled, let us return to the attempted solution in the question. Let $D = \bigcup_{i=1}^\infty D_i$ and note that $D \in \mathcal J$ by assumption. By one of DeMorgan's laws,
$$A_n = D \setminus \left( \bigcup_{i=1}^n D_i \right) = \bigcap_{i=1}^n (D \setminus D_i).$$
Each of the sets $D \setminus D_i$ is a finite union of disjoint sets in $\mathcal J$ (by what we found earlier). That is, for each $i \in \{1,\dots,n\}$,
$$D \setminus D_i = J_{i1} \cup \dots \cup J_{i k_i}$$
for some collection of disjoint sets $J_{i1}, \dots, J_{i k_i} \in \mathcal J$. Hence
$$A_n = \bigcap_{i=1}^n \bigcup_{j=1}^{k_i} J_{ij}.$$
With a little work, one finds that this intersection of unions is equal to the following union of intersections:
$$A_n = \bigcup_{j_1=1}^{k_1} \dots \bigcup_{j_n=1}^{k_n} \bigcap_{i=1}^n J_{i j_i}.$$
Now we are done. Each of the sets $\bigcap_{i=1}^n J_{i j_i} = J_{1 j_1} \cap \dots \cap J_{n j_n}$ is an element of $\mathcal J$ by closure under finite intersection. Moreover, for any two distinct such sets $J_{1 j_1} \cap \dots \cap J_{n j_n}$ and $J_{1 j'_1} \cap \dots \cap J_{n j'_n}$ we must have $j_i \ne j'_i$ for some $i$, which makes them disjoint since $J_{i j_i}$ and $J_{i j'_i}$ are disjoint.
